# Conversion of varchar to time failed in SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, time, varchar

> My table:

[image]

> When I convert it to time, it fails while selecting from table:

[image]

> But, when I test it in string, then there is no issue. What is the problem? I don't know.

[image]

Comment: Why are you storing time in a varchar? Read Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select CONVERT(time, substring((CASE TimOut WHEN '0' THEN '00:00' ELSE TimOut END),1,5),104) from tbl_test
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you have new line in your time column. Please use substring to get exact time.

```
select CONVERT(time, substring(timout, 1, 5), 104) 
from tbl_test
```

Convert will create problem when time is null or invalid so use **Len** function.

```
select CONVERT(time, substring(timout, 1, 5), 104) 
from tbl_test  
where len(TimOut) > 4
```

Comment: if length is greater than 4 or less than what ?

Comment: you can use case statement.

Comment: then use  case statement and convert the less than 4 digit time to that equall to 4 digit. like below answer